# How can I convert a lambda function arguments and store it in std::function

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I have a list of functions stored in a vector:

```cpp
std::vector<std::function<void(uint32_t)>> mFunctions;
```

I want to add a function as a public API that accepts a different argument but casts it to uint32_t:

```cpp
enum class MyHandle : uint32_t { Null = 0; };


void addFunction(std::function<void(MyHandle)> &&fn) {
  mFunctions.push_back(fn);
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What is the underlying and actual problem you're trying to solve? Why do you have differing function signatures? Why do you want to store both sets of functions in a single container? Why can't you just change the argument type for either the functions in the vector, or for the function passed to `addFunction`?

Comment: Does the _function_ cast the `MyHandle` to `uint32_t` or do _you_ want to cast the `uint32_t` to `MyHandle` when you call the function?

Comment: I'm confused after reading your question again carefully: Do you want to cast _to_ `uint32_t` or to `MyHandle` _from_ `uint32_t? I assume the latter.

Comment: The idea was that internally I have one vector of `uint32_t` accepting functions from users of the API, they pass `enum class` for compile time guarantees on what the function accepts. These functions are also mapped to another data structure and there are many handles. So, I did not want to create >10 separate vectors and keep it simple.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You simply have to do the cast yourself and invoke the function with the casted argument by wrapping it in a lambda:

```
void addFunction(std::function<void(MyHandle)> fn) {
    mFunctions.push_back([fn = std::move(fn)](uint32_t value) {
        fn(MyHandle{ value });
    });
}
```

Since we're already at it, I would recommend that the `addFunction` method should be a template parameterized on the callback argument. This way you prevent a lot of overhead of the type erasure, since you don't have two layers of `std::function`:

```
template <std::invocable<MyHandle> F>
void addFunction(F&& fn) {
    mFunctions.push_back([fn = std::forward<F>(fn)](uint32_t value) {
        std::invoke(fn, MyHandle{ value });
    });
}
```

If you don't have access to C++20 it would look like this:

```
template <typename F>
void addFunction(F&& fn) {
    mFunctions.push_back([fn = std::forward<F>(fn)](uint32_t value) {
        std::invoke(fn, MyHandle{ value });
    });
}
```

[Here is an example of the code in action](https://godbolt.org/z/fxfzqcTr6)

Comment: `MyHandle{value}` would be enough for the conversion and is weaker than a `static_cast`. In particular it would produce a diagnostic on narrowing. Since the function takes a forwarding reference, `fn=std::forward<...>(fn)` for the capture might be better. (But then again OP is using a rvalue reference and doesn't move it either.)

Comment: Thank you, good suggestions. It didn't `std::forward` because it makes the code very verbose. It would be the correct thing todo though, so I'm not sure which way to go here. And I will edit in the suggestions about the enum cast

Comment: I prefer using `const` references instead of forwarding references if I don't actually forward in the body. Then it doesn't read like a mistake anymore. Similarly in OP's code I would use a `const` reference as well if there won't be any move from the reference. But yes, it is just a matter of preference.

Comment: @user17732522 Alright, I edited it to use `std::forward`. It's actually not that bad with an explicit template declaration. Also good suggestion to use const references otherwise, I can see that it may prevent confusion.